# Host a custom DNS with custom TLD's

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind9

*There's so many Stack Overflow sites. Pardon me if this is posted on the wrong site.*

I got to thinking, and started wondering what's stopping somebody from running a custom DNS. Sure, not many would use it, but those who did would be able to register .whatever domain names. Theoretically if I wanted to accomplish this what steps would I need to take?

My ideal setup would allow me to easily setup custom root domains, but also access the rest of the real internet (when utilizing the DNS). So I could visit name.whatever, but still be able to visit google.com if necessary.

Comment: There was some concern a few years back that China would start doing exactly that, and that there was enough anti-ICANN (i.e., US) sentiment that countries would adopt those root servers. http://www.digitaltrends.com/web/u-s-surrendering-control-internet/
Internally to your own network, you can run DNS with whatever TLDs you want or need.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing technical is stopping you, and quite a few people do exactly what you're thinking of. There is even a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_DNS_root) about it.